# SQL select group and filter

Tags: sql

Following data is in a database table

```
Color   MADE    MODEL   REG
-----   ----    -----   ----
Red     TOYOTA  CAR     EN-9082   *
Yellow  TOYOTA  CAR     YR-4356   *
Red     TOYOTA  JEP     AX-4566
Yellow  TOYOTA  SUV     AX-4343
Yellow  NISSAN  CAR     ER-0873
Yellow  HONDA   SUV     AS-6453   *    ^
Red     HONDA   SUV     SD-9853   *    ^
Blue    HONDA   SUV     AS-9762        ^
```

I have to write a code to extract records indicated by '*' (no aggregation just filter them) when colors 'Red' and 'Yellow' passed in.

Similarly if I pass colors 'Red', 'Yellow' and 'Blue' I need the records indicated by '^'

In other words I need records where all passed in colors are available for the Made and Model combination.

On the other hand I cannot use the color names in the SQL. They are passed in to my program and I do not have a control over them.

Is it possible to write a SQL which will ideally use pure-SQL. I need to execute it against multiple databases (Ex. Oracle, SQL Service, Informix)

Ish

Comment: You cannot use just SQL, be available for all DBMS and then say you don't want hard-coded values. Those 3 don't marry.
There must be some way to pass those values and it's either in the code (injecting the arguments in the SQL provided by **vkp**) or some sort of stored procedure (MSSQL).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. `having` can be extended for the other color combinations.

```
select *
from tablename 
where made in (select made
               from tablename
               group by made
               having count(case when color in ('Red','Yellow') then 1 end) >= 2)
```

Comment: @vpk Thanks for your answer. But I cannot hard code the colors. Those will be passed in parameters. I should have mentioned in the question. I will update it

Comment: i don't understand why you can't use parameters in this query. Instead of hard-coded values you can pass in the parameters

Comment: @vpk, I got it wrong. Yes I can put parameters into the query. I will check it again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

vkp's answer is basically correct.  I think it is more simply written as:

```
select t.*
from tablename  t.
where made in (select t2.made
               from tablename t2
               where t2.color in ('Red', 'Yellow')
               group by t2.made
               having count(*) = 2
              );
```

If duplicates are permitted, then the `having` clause should be `count(distinct color) = 2`.